# Recycler ItemDecoration item appearing over recycler view items

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, stickyrecycleview

I needed to add sticky header in recyclerview. I used `RosterRecyclerItemDecoration` and it gave me the desired result.

The issue is that the `Decorator` item is appearing over the items of `recycler view`.

I want to add decorator item in between of recyclerview items and not over recyclerview items.

This is my code.

```
RosterRecyclerItemDecoration rosterRecyclerItemDecoration =
                new RosterRecyclerItemDecoration(true,
                        this);
 rvLeaders.addItemDecoration(rosterRecyclerItemDecoration);
```

**Decorator Class:**

```
 public class RosterRecyclerItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {


 public RosterRecyclerItemDecoration(boolean sticky,@NonNull IDecoraterCallback iDecoraterCallback){
        this.sticky= sticky;
        this.iDecoraterCallback= iDecoraterCallback;
    }



    @Override
    public void onDrawOver(@NonNull Canvas c, @NonNull RecyclerView parent, @NonNull RecyclerView.State state) {
        super.onDrawOver(c, parent, state);

        CharSequence previousHeader = "";

        if (headerView == null) {
            headerView = inflateHeaderView(parent);
            header = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.tvHeader);
            fixLayoutSize(headerView, parent);
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
            final int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(child);

            if(iDecoraterCallback.getSectionHeader(position) !=null) {
                CharSequence title = iDecoraterCallback.getSectionHeader(position);
                header.setText(title);

                if (!previousHeader.equals(title)) {                
                    drawHeader(c, child, headerView);
                    previousHeader = title;
                    }  
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to use **Rect** to draw your decorator. In your `RosterRecyclerItemDecoration`  Constructor you can pass a height like 40 or 50 dp it is dpend on your Layout.

Now In your `RosterRecyclerItemDecoration` class override `getItemOffsets` It looks like:

```
public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state);
}
```

in this override method you can set your height. Like `outRect.top = headerOffset;` [Check this view is your sectionHeader]

**Note:** Here headerOffset is height that you send in your `RosterRecyclerItemDecoration` constructor.